# Unable to start Gradle deamon in fresh install of Android Studio 0.8.1

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I wanted to start some Android app development with my friend recently. I've installed the latest Android Studio 0.8.1 and cloned github repo. Then, when I try to build the project using Gradle, it is failing with the message:

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.12/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

I am using Windows 8.1 64bit, JDK jdk1.7.0_60 64bit and gradle 1.12

I tried to:
- disable firewall and antivirus - didn't help 
- download gradle manually, unzip and copy to .gradle in my home directory - didn't help 
- when I open a blank new app I have same problem 
- I moved the app to different directory as my user name contains 'ł' - same issue

Can anyone look at the log and try to help? This is the most annoying kind of issues developer can face - env is refusing to work and you can't code :(

<<< [link to log](http://pastebin.com/08Wd8CPY) >>>

Comment: Try to upgrade to the latest version of Android Studio (that's, 0.8.2 as if this writing) and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you installed jdk and gradle with different users?

Comment: Hi, I was thinking about that also because my first installation of Android studio was for "only current user". So I have uninstalled it and installed again for "all users" but it didn't help. But finally... somehow, I have manage to run it! I will place answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after quite long fight last night, I have managed to run Android studio and build project with Gradle... and I hope it will stay so.

So, as @Eugen pointed out, this could be related to the fact that first installation of Android Studio was done for "only current user". Even I have uninstalled it and installed again it was still failing. Last night, I decided to uninstall it and also, manually, remove all remains of android stuff by simply deleting every directory with android, gradle etc. in its name ;)

I have also updated java to 7.65. and installed stand alone Gradle 2.0 and add it to PATH and check it is working.

After that, I done a clean install of android studio and open simple new MyApp project... and it works! Then I opened my other project - also working! I removed Gradle from PATH - still working.

I have no idea what was wrong... probably first installation of Android Studio was not completely correct. And unistalling it, didn't removed everything.

So, I have no clear answer for my issues, but I thought it could be helpful to describe the story. :)